# Find IPs of network between two nodes

Tags: networking

I have two servers connected on the same subnet with each other. I would like to know which switches come in between the two servers. I do have admin and physical access to the boxes but they are all plugged in and I would like the least intrusive way to know about IPs of the switches in between.

I guess I would have to go a level down than TCP/IP for this, map the ethernet addresses some how to IPs but not really sure.

Comment: heres where a physical network diagram comes in really handy :)

Comment: I am trying to make one without tearing up every thing and without going through a mess of wires that is called the switch room :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have admin access to the switches?

If so the easiest way would be to get the mac address of your servers and then check the mac address tables on the switches to see which ports they see your server through, then build up a picture that way. If you're lucky the ports may already have labels on them, otherwise use CDP or LLDP to discover how the switches are connected together. If you have a several multipathed switches then you life is a little more difficult. If you have lots of servers you need to map then perhaps you should look at something along the lines of [mactrack](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:mactrack) or [network tracking database](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netdbtracking/)

If not I think you might be looking at a cable chase!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the layer of your switches, you might be able to use the switch software to map your network (works for HP/3com managed switches etc).